# Tap gesture on UILabel beside a UIPageControl not working

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipagecontrol

I have a `UILabel` on both sides of a `UIPageControl`, as pictured below:

[image: Screen shot]

I found that tapping on the sides of the `UIPageControl` the dot would progress, ie not on my arrows and not triggering a method of mine.  But nothing else would change, so I set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the `UIPageControl`.

I connected (via `UITapGestureRecognizer`) another `UILabel` above and it launches a method fine.
However the `UILabel`s, beside the `UIPageControl`, will not work.  NOTE: I do have `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `true` on this element.  (I even temporarily changed the element to a `UIButton` and it wouldn't work either - so I reverted back to my `UILabel`.)

So, is there a way to add a `UILabel` to the side of a `UIPageControl` that gets triggered?  Alternately, can the invisible objects (while tapping on the left or right of the `UIPageControl` - like in my second sentence) be connected to a custom method?

**UPDATE:**

I've added another separate modal (same title label, buttons, but no collection view and no page control).  Again it won't respond when I press the label in the centre, but I temporarily am using the title label which responses and launches my method fine.

Can anyone say why?

Comment: check if your pagecontrol  frame over Labels or not

Comment: that's something I though of. can you explain how to set this?

Comment: just set background to dark and check if frame label visible or not

Comment: background colour doesn't cover the labels and the constraints are H:|-2-[v0(25)]-2-[v1]-2-[v2(25)]-2-|" where v0 is back, v1 is the pagecontrol and v2 is next

Comment: are you set them in UIstackView

Comment: tried both ways - same results.  Anyway the constraints are basically the same using a h.stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue!

I was declaring most variables - as well as the UILabel - in closures blocks, at the top of the class, like below:

```
let myLabel: UILabel = {
{
  let view = UILabel()
  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  view.textColor = UIColor.blue
  return view
}
```

Within this closure I had **`view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doMyLabelMethod(_:))))`** and **`view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`**, when I moved them out of the closure and placed them directly above **`addSubview(myLabel)`** it fired fine.

So variable-closures are good to contain many dressing, but not gesture recognizers!